# Django filter objects with at least one many-to-many having attribute of value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm looking to do a complex filter using Django's ORM.

**Models:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    books = models.ManytoManyField(Book)
```

How would I query for all authors who have at least one best-selling book?

**Query:**

```
best_authors = Author.objects.filter(<relevant filter>)
```

---

**Edit:**

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), the following should work:

```
best_authors = Author.objects.filter(books__bestseller=True)
```

Unfortunately, that ends up returning repeated author objects (the same author for each bestselling book of his/hers, over and over).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
best_authors = Author.objects.filter(books__bestseller=True).distinct()
```

The `filter()` does a `JOIN` with the `Books` table and produces all rows where `bestseller==True`. The `distinct()` ensures that each author is listed only once in the results.