# Filter based on number of manytomany

Tags: python, django

I have models defined as follow:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  ...
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Project(models.Model):
  ...
  employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the projects that have at least one employee assigned to them, but I don't know how. I tried the following things:

`projects.filter(employees__gt=0)`

where `projects = Project.objects.all()` but I don't think this is the right query, because if I do `projects.filter(employees_lte=0)` it returns nothing, even if I have projects with no employees assigned. How can I retrieve what I'm looking for? Could you point to a page where I can find all the lookups I can use?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django filter objects with at least one many-to-many having attribute of value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026314/django-filter-objects-with-at-least-one-many-to-many-having-attribute-of-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [**`isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
Project.objects.filter(employees__isnull=False)
```

---

#### Update

If you want to check specific number of employees, maybe try like this

```
from django.db.models import Count

Project.objects.annotate(employee_count=Count('employees')).filter(employee_count__gt=5)
```

Comment: this works, thank you! One question though: what if would I like to check if there is a specific number of elements linked? How should I do it?